# How to select all text in Winforms NumericUpDown upon tab in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

When the user tabs into my `NumericUpDown` I would like all text to be selected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
private void NumericUpDown1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericUpDown1.Select(0, NumericUpDown1.Text.Length);
}
```

(Note that the Text property is hidden in Intellisense, but it's there)

Comment: @Jon: Darn intellisense :-/  Good call with the Text property.

Comment: I was just trying to do this during form construction (set focus to a specific NumericUpDown and select all its text). I had to call `Select()` AND `Select(0, NumericUpDown1.Text.Length);`, the first to set the focus and the second to select the text. So, a note for anyone else who comes here looking for a way to do what I was doing: You have to make both of those calls to get the result you want, even though both are named the same thing (I kept expecting the call to `Select(start, length)` to also set the focus like `Select()` did)

Comment: "if you focus the control using the tab key, this code will do fine but if you focus it with a click, although it passes through the method, it won't select the text. My guess is that this code is called before some internal framework code that puts the cursor reseting the selection. To bypass this you can put this same code in the click event handler", `n0n4m3`  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/28354bc2-3903-4be4-9c2c-3249319b59fd

Comment: Lambda event handler `m_numericUpDown.GotFocus += (o, e) => m_numericUpDown.Select(0, m_numericUpDown.Text.Length);` or  `m_numericUpDown.Click += (o, e) => m_numericUpDown.Select(0, m_numericUpDown.Text.Length);`. I didn't use the OnClick because I prefer not to have text highlighted except on Tab and double-clicking highlights as default behaviour.

Comment: if it has a decimal point then use this *NumericUpDown1.Select(0, NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString().Length + NumericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces + 2);*

Change *2* according number of decimal points it has

use it in Click and Enter events of NumericUpDown1

Answer (score 14):

I wanted to add to this for future people who have been search for Tab and Click.

Jon B answer works perfect for Tab but I needed to modify to include click

Below will select the text if you tab in or click in.  If you click and you enter the box then it will select the text.  If you are already focused on the box then the click will do what it normally does.

```
    bool selectByMouse = false;

    private void quickBoxs_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown curBox = sender as NumericUpDown;
        curBox.Select();
        curBox.Select(0, curBox.Text.Length);
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            selectByMouse = true;
        }
    }

    private void quickBoxs_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown curBox = sender as NumericUpDown;
        if (selectByMouse)
        {
            curBox.Select(0, curBox.Text.Length);
            selectByMouse = false;
        }
    }
```

You can use this for multiple numericUpDown controls.  Just need to set the Enter and MouseDown Events

Comment: If the selection source is irrelevant one may use quickBox_Enter(...) for both events.

Comment: It has been a long time but I believe I needed this way because clicking in the box I only wanted to select everything if it was the first time selecting the box with the mouse.  If tabbed in then always select everything.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking around i had the same issue and this Works for me, first select the Item and the second one selects the Text, hope it helps in future

```
myNumericUpDown.Select();
 myNumericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Value.ToString().Length);
```

Comment: This is what I was considering doing before I realized that NumericUpDown.Text does exist, you just wont get IntelliSense to show it to you, you may even get it trying to autocomplete you to TextAlign.

"The Text has no affect on the appearance of the NumericUpDown control; therefore, it is hidden in the designer and from IntelliSense." -Microsoft  I also tested entering values in with the .Text interface because autism and it works as expected, throwing exceptions for non numeric values and replacing what you enter with max and min values if you exceed them.

Comment: it's been a while since you commented @user2163234 I'm glad to see you figure it out, sometimes autocompleters doesn't help as it should, or us get to used to work with them.

Comment: Note that NumericUpDown.Value.ToString() may strip configured decimal places which are hard to recover.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension method to accomplish this:

VB:

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Sub SelectAll(myNumericUpDown As NumericUpDown)
    myNumericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Text.Length)
End Sub
```

C#:

```cs
public static void SelectAll(this NumericUpDown numericUpDown)
    numericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Text.Length)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple numericupdown box's and wanted to achieve this for all. I created:

```
private void num_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumericUpDown box = sender as NumericUpDown;
    box.Select();
    box.Select(0, num_Shortage.Value.ToString().Length);
}
```

Then by associating this function with the Enter Event for each box (which I didn't do), my goal was achieved. Took me a while to figure out as I am a beginner. Hope this helps someone else out

Comment: this is effectively a duplicate of the accepted answer

Comment: @AidanRyan Actually, since this answer uses `sender` instead of a fixed object target, it's arguably better than the accepted answer.

Comment: This answers the original question plus a question that wasn't asked. How to handle a common event across controls is a different concern, regardless of selecting all text or anythign else you might want to do with the event. Really it just adds noise.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting all text by mouse click or by Tab button I use:

```
    public frmMain() {
        InitializeComponent();
        numericUpDown1.Enter += numericUpDown_SelectAll;
        numericUpDown1.MouseUp += numericUpDown_SelectAll;
    }

    private void numericUpDown_SelectAll(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        NumericUpDown box = sender as NumericUpDown;
        box.Select(0, box.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 myNumericUpDown.Select(0, myNumericUpDown.Value.ToString().Length);
```

Comment: Can you add any clarification as to why it works, what the various pieces of this do?

Comment: This will fail if you have a decimal places and the value with no fraction (ex: 99.00) the value will be 99 so the length of the value will be 2